# Create an exe compatible with all versions of windows 64-bit and 32-bit even if python isn't installed with pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.6

I have used **pyinstaller** to create an exe from a python script on Windows 10 64-bit. How can i setup the exe so that it runs on my other machine with Windows 8 32-bit. Please note i have not installed python in the Windows 8 laptop and i  do not intend to. I am relatively new to python and i'm using python 3.6. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/peterwachira7/csm#csm). I have built the setup.py file which imports all the other files.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
here is my setup.spec file.... it's unchanged because i did not know how to modify it. and below it is the output when i run **pyinstaller setup.py**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['setup.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\grey_hat\\Desktop\\csm\\test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='setup',
          debug=True,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )


C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test>pyinstaller setup.py
4109 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3
4109 INFO: Python: 3.6.3
4109 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.10586-SP0
4125 INFO: wrote C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\setup.spec
4140 INFO: UPX is not available.
4156 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\grey_hat\\Desktop\\csm\\test',
 'C:\\Users\\grey_hat\\Desktop\\csm\\test']
4171 INFO: checking Analysis
4296 INFO: Building because C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\setup.py changed
4312 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
4343 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
4453 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
14156 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
14218 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\grey_hat\python.exe
14328 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python.exe
14359 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python.exe
14375 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python.exe
14406 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python.exe
14437 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python.exe
14671 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14703 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14734 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14765 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14796 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14812 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14843 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14875 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14890 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14921 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14953 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
14984 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
15015 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\VCRUNTIME140.dll
15046 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\VCRUNTIME140.dll
15078 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\VCRUNTIME140.dll
15093 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\VCRUNTIME140.dll
15125 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\VCRUNTIME140.dll
15140 INFO: Caching module hooks...
15187 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\setup.py
16921 INFO: Loading module hooks...
16921 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
17062 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
17734 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
18156 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
18156 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
18156 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
18171 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
18171 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module PIL.ImageQt
18171 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
18171 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module PIL.ImageQt
18171 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
18187 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
18187 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
18187 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
18187 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
18187 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
18203 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
18218 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
18421 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
19031 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
19125 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
19140 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
19187 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
19343 INFO: checking Tree
19828 INFO: checking Tree
19984 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
20078 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
20093 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
20093 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
20125 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
20156 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20187 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20218 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20250 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20281 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20328 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20359 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20390 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20406 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20437 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
20546 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
20562 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
20593 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
20625 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
20656 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
20687 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
20718 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
20750 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
20796 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
20828 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
20875 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
20906 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
20921 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
20953 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
20984 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
21015 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
21046 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
21078 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
21140 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
21171 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
21187 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
21218 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
21265 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
21296 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
21343 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_socket.pyd
21375 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_socket.pyd
21421 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\select.pyd
21468 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_sqlite3.pyd
21500 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_sqlite3.pyd
21546 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_sqlite3.pyd
21609 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
21625 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
21656 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
21687 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
21718 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
21734 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
21765 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
21843 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
21875 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
21906 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
21937 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22046 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22078 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22109 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22140 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22171 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22203 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22234 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22265 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22281 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22343 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingtk.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22375 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingtk.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22421 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingtk.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22437 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingtk.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
22484 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
22515 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
22546 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
22593 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\sqlite3.dll
22625 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\sqlite3.dll
22656 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\sqlite3.dll
22671 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\sqlite3.dll
22703 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\sqlite3.dll
22734 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\sqlite3.dll
22828 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
22859 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
22906 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
22937 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
22968 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
23000 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
23031 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
23062 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
23078 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
23171 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tk86t.dll
23234 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tk86t.dll
23250 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tk86t.dll
23312 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tk86t.dll
23359 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tk86t.dll
23390 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tk86t.dll
23421 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tk86t.dll
23453 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\grey_hat\DLLs\tk86t.dll
23468 INFO: Looking for eggs
23468 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\grey_hat\python36.dll
23468 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
23484 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\build\setup\warnsetup.txt
23609 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\build\setup\xref-setup.html
23734 INFO: checking PYZ
23765 INFO: Building because toc changed
23765 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\build\setup\out00-PYZ.pyz
24812 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\build\setup\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
24828 INFO: checking PKG
24890 INFO: Building because toc changed
24890 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
25015 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
25015 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\grey_hat\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
25015 INFO: checking EXE
25109 INFO: Building because name changed
25109 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
25140 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\build\setup\setup.exe
25359 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
25359 INFO: checking COLLECT
WARNING: The output directory "C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\dist\setup" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/n)y
28109 INFO: Removing dir C:\Users\grey_hat\Desktop\csm\test\dist\setup
29359 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
41468 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: Have you tried it "as is"? Are there an issues you specifically encountered?

Comment: Yes. Trying to run it on windows 8 gives an error."this application can't run on your pc"

Comment: can you post the output of your pyinstaller run, as well as your spec file and the command you used to compile.

Comment: @The4thIceman i have updated my question. I hope that's what you asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Windows 10 and PyInstaller do not play well together. Your program will run on your system, but on other (earlier) Windows systems it will not. This has to do with all those warnings about missing dlls and dependencies. The following link offers a lot more information and solutions:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1566

Below was my solution to the problem (taken from the above link):

1) Download and install this Windows SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

2) These dlls can then be found here (or Program Files x86):

```
 C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs
```

3) Update your pathex variable in your spec file to tell pyinstaller to look there:

```
pathex=['C:\\Users\\grey_hat\\Desktop\\csm\\test', 
        'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Redist\\ucrt\\DLLs\\x86',
        'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Redist\\ucrt\\DLLs\\x64']
```

4) run pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller yourspecfile.spec
```

This may not be the only solution, but it is how I got it working for my setup.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give you my feedback when I do it.

Comment: Were you able to link the dll and test it on a 32 bit?