# compatibility with other windows versions PyInstaller after build

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I have a kivy build project with Pyinstaller on Window 10. it works fine on my Windows 10 64 PC, but when I try to run on another machine it returns me the following error.

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of windows
> running. Consult your computer's system information to see if you need
> an x86 (32bit) or x64 (64bit) version of the program and contact the
> software publisher

**It my machine setup:**

- Python 3.7.6 x32
- pyinstaller 4.0.dev0
  ...

And this is my **test.spec**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer

a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\bababa\\Desktop\\mask\\Main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\bababa\\Desktop\\mask', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Redist\\ucrt\\DLLs\\x86','C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Redist\\ucrt\\DLLs\\x64'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Mask',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='C:\\Users\\bababa\\Desktop\\mask\\icons\\icoagta.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,Tree('C:\\Users\\bababa\\Desktop\\mask'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins + gstreamer.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Mask')
```

I tried many solutions but none worked

Method run:
***python -m PyInstaller test.spec***

Comment: You may need to include several `dlls` with your executable, See the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#platform-specific-notes-windows).

Comment: I tryed this solution but's dont work 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155474/create-an-exe-compatible-with-all-versions-of-windows-64-bit-and-32-bit-even-if